# silverstripe v3 drag and drop reordering issue

Tags: drag-and-drop, silverstripe

Good morning,

I've recently started looking into SilverStripe framework due to it's reviews, and most importantly license. I usually develop using other popular cms systems but their license is GPL and doesn't suit this project. My issue is that it's not well documented when it comes to module development.

I would like to enable a simple drag & drop re-ordering on the backend interface for a custom module, see code below:

```
class MyManager extends ModelAdmin{

    static $managed_models = array('MyTask');       
    static $url_segment = 'mymgr';
    static $menu_title = 'My Manager';

    public function getCMSFields(){ 
        $fields=parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.MyTask', 
            GridField::create(
                    'MyTask', 
                    'Data Object', 
                    $this->MyTask(), 
                    GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create() 
                    ->addComponent(new GridFieldSortableRows('Weight'))
            ) 
        );
        return $fields; 
    }

}//class

class MyTask extends DataObject{
    static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar',
        'Description' => 'Text',
        'Weight' => 'Int',
        'IsActive' => 'Boolean'
    );
}//MyTask
```

Note: I've read through this already (http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/20323), did not help much.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `ModelAdmin`, you should be using the `getEditForm` method (not `getCMSFields`), which generates the CMS form. So all you have to do is add a component to the GridField and that should do it:

```
public function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null)
{
  $form = parent::getEditForm($id, $fields);

  $tasksGridField = $form->Fields()->fieldByName('MyTask');

  if ($tasksGridField)
  {
      $tasksGridField->getConfig()->addComponent(new GridFieldSortableRows('Weight'));
  }

  return $form;
}
```

You could/should also add a `private static $default_sort = 'Weight ASC'` to your `MyTask` DataObject so they are displayed in the right order by default.

Comment: Thanks. It works as expected. Can you point me in the direction where I can get proper documentation? Thanks.

Comment: You can check the `ModelAdmin` doc, there is quite a bit about customizing and extending the interface http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/modeladmin#results-customization with examples on how to add extra components to the GF...

Comment: Thanks. Been going through the API, tutorials, etc. I don't know if I can ask another SS related question here, or if I need to re-post: Basically, I have an enum in a DataObject and would like to display it in ModelAdmin GridField view. Can't, find anything on it.
Tried this but it didn't work:
[code]
    $gridField = $form->Fields()->fieldByName('EnumFieldName');
       if ($gridField) {
         $gridField->getConfig()->addComponent(new GridFieldFilterHeader());
       }
[/code]

Comment: This is usually done through the DataObject summaray_field static, nothing more. Best to post this in another question though, easier to look/answer.

Comment: Okay noted. Thanks a lot for all your help, it's much appreciated.